# Same script 2 Google Sheets tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a script that I want to make work for 2 tabs of a Google Spreadsheet. I get the error

> "The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet."

For one of them, but the other works just fine with the same script. Below is the script, trying to filter for only the 2 sheets.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() === "Successful Guide Searches") {
    if (editedCell.getColumn() == 2) {
      var range = sheet.getRange("A1:C1000");
      range.sort([{ column: 2, ascending: false }, { column: 3, ascending: true }]);
    }
  }
  if (sheet.getName() === "Failed Guide Searches") {
    if (editedCell.getColumn() == 2) {
      var range = sheet.getRange("A1:C1000");
      range.sort([{ column: 2, ascending: false }, { column: 3, ascending: true }]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there's a thousand rows in both sheets? What if you used `sheet.getRange("A1:C")`?

Comment: For some reason, I think the code editor change it on its own, but yes that's what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const shts = ["Successful Guide Searches", "Failed Guide Searches"];
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const rg = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), 3);
  if (~shts.indexOf(sh.getName()) && e.range.columnStart == 2) {
    rg.sort([{ column: 2, ascending: false }, { column: 3, ascending: true }]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't realize it was the exact same procedure on both sheets so I cleaned up mine. Yours is probably more efficient, but some of us less skilled folks (like me) might struggle with the ~ thing (which you already explained to me but i still struggle with).

Comment: The tilde is a bitWise Not.  So in this case the only time it's false is when the returned value is a minus one.  In all other cases it's truthiness will be true which means that sh.getName() is within the shts array.  It's the same thing as writing shts.indexOf() != -1

Comment: Is it possible it was getting the range from one tab, but using that range on the other tab?  I know they are different sizes, and may never do the same.

Comment: Thanks. @Cooper. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're either calling your trigger wrong or you aren't scoping your ranges correctly. Using the below modified code on [this sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ufy_Z-Poi4i8sBvxoqFPkzXWiCujeRWScD4h0MLU03w/edit#gid=0), I was able to get it to run as I would expect.

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

function onEdit(e) {
  var theRange = e.range;
  var sheet = theRange.getSheet();
  var theSheetName = sheet.getName();
  if (theSheetName === "Successful Guide Searches" ||
    theSheetName === "Failed Guide Searches" &&
    theRange.getColumn() == 2) {
      var range = sheet.getRange("A1:C");
      range.sort([{ column: 2, ascending: false }, { column: 3, ascending: true }]);
    }
}
```